# Send data from Fragment to its parent Activity and refresh the parent

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I want to pass code from fragment to its parent activity. The fragment contains a list and I want when press item in list to pass data to the mainActivity when do  `list.setOnItemClickListener` meaning that send data everytime the user selects and item from list.

hope anyone could help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please read the documentation. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the activity with "getActivity()" and cast it. You may let your activity implement an interface to call it's method from the fragment: your activity and fragment will then be loosely coupled.

INTERFACE:

```
interface MyItemClick{
       public void onItemClick();
}
```

ACTIVITY:

```
class MyActivity extends activity implements MyItemClick{
       public void onItemClick(){
          //TODO
       }
}
```

FRAGMENT:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    ///ETC...

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
           ((MyItemClick) MyFragment.this).getActivity()).onItemClick();
    });

    ///ETC...

}
```

Comment: Could you show me sample code, please?

Comment: There are an error in ((MyItemClick) MyFragment.this).getActivity()).onItemClick();

Comment: This works `MyItemClick myItemClick = (MyItemClick) getActivity();
     myItemClick.onItemClick();`